# Using matrix in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to use a matrix in VHDL here's what I've done so far:

```
type MAT is array ( 7 downto 0 ) of bit_vector( 9 downto 0);
signal MAT_WORD:MAT:= (others=>X"00");
signal BREAKCODe :NATURAL:=0;



for I in 9 downto 0 loop 
                        if(MAT_WORD(I) = x"88") then 
                            BREAKCODE <= I;
                        end if ;
                    end loop; 

............
```

I get an error that I get is that :

```
Implicit array operator "=" always returns FALSE (left length 10 is not equal to right length 8
```

any idea how can use the loop or the matrix as one with 8 columns and 10 rows ?

Comment: Compare against 10 bit values.

Comment: But I want evaluate a 8 bit vector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers you've received so far provide bits and pieces, in part because your code is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

There are standard version issues with a comprehensive answer, otherwise Matthew Sainsbury's answer is spot on for -2008 compliant simulators and synthesis tools. In IEEE Std 1076-2008, 15.8 Bit string literals, an option length prefix of an integer value has been added, allowing in the case of base X for 0 filling the resulting bit string with a length longer than the value provided by the following bit string literal value.

In lieu of -2008 tools you can use concatenation (which is how the bit string literal is 'stretched' by length in -2008) or in a limited number of cases aggregation with an `others` choice (and none of those cases are present in the following example):

```
entity engine is
end entity;

architecture foo of engine is

    type MAT is array ( 9 downto 0 ) of bit_vector( 9 downto 0);
    signal MAT_WORD: MAT := (others =>  ( others => '0'));
    signal BREAKCODE: NATURAL := 0;

begin
    MAT_WORD(5) <= "00" & x"88";

SCAN:
    process(MAT_WORD)
    begin
        BREAKCODE <= 0;     -- when no "0010001000" occurs, clear BREAKCODE
        for I in  MAT_WORD'range loop 
            if MAT_WORD(I) = "00" & x"88"  then 
                BREAKCODE <= I;
            end if;
        end loop; 
    end process;
NARK:
    process (BREAKCODE)
    begin
        if BREAKCODE > 0 then
            report "MAT_WORD(" & integer'image(BREAKCODE) & 
                    ") = ""00"" & x""88""";
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The above code analyzes, elaborates and runs:

> ghdl -a engine.vhdl
>   ghdl -e engine
>   ghdl -r engine
>   engine.vhdl:27:13:@0ms:(report note): MAT_WORD(5) = "00" & x"88"

And you can see it reports the location the concurrent signal assignment writes.

Note there was one additional error in your code where you declare the range of `I` in the loop statement to have a range `9 downto 0` which is out of range for type `MAT`. That has been corrected here by using correcting the range of `MAT`.  (The loop constant `I` has been modified to use the range of the declared object, allowing you to change the size of your matrix in exactly one place).

You could also use an incomplete type declaration:

```
type MAT is array (natural range <>)  of bit_vector (9 downto 0);
```

and specify the range in the object declaration:

```
signal MAT_WORD:  MAT (9 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
```

Fixing the range in the type declaration seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed up the dimensions. You defined a matrix with 8 elements `(7 downto 0)` where each element stores a 10-bit vector `(9 downto 0)`.

In your for-loop you can only iterate through the elements and check each element against a 10-bit vector. For example:

```
process(MAT_WORD)
begin
  BREAK_CODE <= 0; -- move initialization here or the following 
                   -- must be encapsulated into a clocked process

  for i in 7 downto 0 loop -- order may be important
    if MAT_WORD(i) = "0010001000" then -- x"88" with two '0' prepended
      BREAK_CODE <= i;
    end if;
  end loop;
end process;
```

Also in the initialization of `MAT_WORD` you must assign 10-bit vectors, e.g,

```
signal MAT_WORD:MAT:= (others=> "0000000000");
```

or more generic:

```
signal MAT_WORD:MAT:= (others=> (others => '0'));
```

Comment: "Also in the initialization of MAT_WORD you must assign 10-bit vectors, e.g,".  Unfortunately your first example shows an aggregate array value length 8  `(others=> ("00000000");`.

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks for the review. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a data width issue? `MAT_WORD(I)` is 10 bits wide, right? and `x"88"` is a hex constant of `0x88` which is an eight-bit constant.

Try

```
if (MAT_WORD(I) = 10x"88")
```

I am not a VHDL user, sorry if this is totally wrong

Edit: Amended code to add the new `10x"88"` syntax

Comment: Defining it as a constant will have the same problem: `x"88"` is 8 bits long so cannot be assigned to a `bit_vector(9 downto 0)`

Comment: I just put this into quartus, and discovered the 10x syntax

Comment: Biit string length is a -2008 innovation and may not be universally supported, particularly by synthesis tools.  IEEE Std 1076-2008 15.8 Bit string literals, para 11 - "If the length is greater than the number of characters in the expanded bit value and the base specifier is B, UB, O, UO, X, UX, or D, the bit string value is obtained by concatenating a string of 0 digits to the left of the expanded bit value. The number of 0 digits in the string is such that the number of characters in the result of the concatenation is the length of the bit string literal."

Answer (score 0):

As Brian says you need to compare against a 10 bit value, as your matrix is composed of an array of 10 bit `bit_vector`.

The hexadecimal literal `x"88"` against which you are comparing is only 8 bits long, hence the error.

Try `if(MAT_WORD(I) = "10001000")` instead - `"10001000"` being the binary representation of `x"88"`.

If you can use VHDL 2000, you have another option - use a sized literal, e.g. `10x"088"`.

In addition you are looping over `9 downto 0` when your `MAT_WORD` array is defined as `7 downto 0`...